# How to share text message on facebook in android programatically

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share some text as well as one picture from my app to facebook wall programatically.
I already registered my android app on facebook developer site.
I am using following code for posting the text but it is not working.It is also not giving me any error so I am totally confused what is happening inside.

```
public class FacebookManager {

private Activity activity;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback;
public UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

public FacebookManager(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    statusCallback = new ShareStatusCallback();
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(activity, null);
}

public void share() {

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions("publish_actions"));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, statusCallback);
    }
}


public void initFbSession(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(activity, null, null, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(activity);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }
}

private class ShareStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (!session.isOpened()) {
            return;
        }
        if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(activity, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
                    .setDescription("Test Message ")
                    //.setPicture("")
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("description", "Test Message");
           // params.putString("picture", "");
            WebDialog feedDialog = (
                    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity,
                            Session.getActiveSession(),
                            params)).build();
            feedDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Does it required any configuration for android app on facebook developer site to use share functionality ?
Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

setDescription only applies if you have a link (via setLink).

You cannot prefill the actual message itself, that's against Facebook's platform policies (the user must type in the message themselves).

We will update the javadocs so that it's more clear.